# Realm Studio - Use Permissions

Tags: realm

Curious if it's possible to edit the permissions of ROS realms from within Realm Studio. Example - I have a global realm (e.g. /globalRealm) and want to allow all users to write to this Realm. Is this possible to do from Realm Studio logged in as an admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to do that. You can write a simple console app to do that though.